# FFMPEG no sound

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to cut a part of a mp4 to make a shorter clip via ffmpeg however when I do I get no sound

```
 ffmpeg -ss 00:06:51 -i truth.mp4 -c:a aac -c:v copy -t 8 true-30sec.mp4
```

The original clip has sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:06:51 -i truth.mp4 -t 8 true-8sec.mp4
```

if you want 30 seconds video from 00:06:51 time, try

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:06:51 -i truth.mp4 -t 30 true-30sec.mp4
```